# How to scan RFid tags with NFC in iOS? Example Code or any SDK?

Tags: ios, rfid

I search lot but didn't found any solution. From where I can find the SDK or any API or any example how to implement.

Comment: iPhone 6. Hopefully ;)

Comment: It is doubtful that NFC will be particularly useful in the near future. The next big change for the US is Chip & PIN cards (most of the rest of the world has been using this technology for a decade) over the next two years. Chip & PIN (also know as EMV) is much more secure, it used a "smart card" like chip which can not be cloned (there is no capability to read its contents) in place of the magnetic stripe that a grade-schooler can scan and clone.

Comment: @Zaph How does the introduction of Chip & PIN contradict NFC (where "NFC" reads "NFC payment" in this case; note that NFC is *much more* than payment)?

Comment: It comes down to technology focus by the Cards and switches. Chip & PIN is a major change that dramatically improves security & reduces fraud on card present transactions. NFC is a neat trick and does not improve either security or reduce fraud. Note: the Cards do not want NFC on a device such as a phone where one can easily select the card, or a rivals card with a tap just a few mili-meters away. In short the Cards do not want to work together. Further all new terminals in the last few years have (by mandate) Chip & PIN, only some have NFC.

Comment: As for "is much more than payment" the question is how wide-spread is that and how desirable to a consumer. I have yet to see an instance there NFC would have been valuable to me. Neat from a technology perspective sure, to the average user: No (IMO). Educate me, what am I missing?

Comment: Hope to see more findings by ios developers as iPhone 6 has NFC support now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No iOS device to this day has NFC hardwares capabilities. You won't find any API or SDK since there isn't. The hardware doesn't exist. Apple chose not to use this technology.

Edit after iPhone 6 keynote:

Apple announced that the iPhone 6 and iPhone 6+ will have NFC hardware so you might be ableto scan RFid tags in iOS. Unfortunately there is no mention of developer access to the NFC controller to perform any NFC operations in iOS 8 docs so far. They did mention in the keynote the possibility to open your hotel room with the watch, so there might be API to access the NFC controller in the future.

Comment: In addition to this: There do exist adapters/covers for iPhones that provide NFC reader functionality.

Comment: I added an edit about possibilities with iPhone 6. NFC hardware will be present though we were not told yet if developer will get access to it.